# Force Browser to open new Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, tabs, popup

Greetings my fellow coders!

I need some help:

I created 2 sites which allow users to create "ClusterLinks" - Links that are related to a database in which multiple, user added links are saved.
You can visit this page at [luckycrew.net](http://luckycrew.net)

(NOTE: At this time, only the "permanent" option works properly)

You can try it out yourself or use this link I just prepared to show you the principe:[The Cluster Gate](http://luckycrew.net/Gate.php?name=Stackoverflow%20-%20Test&hash=1762ea2f909c09e58805ead3a0ae1544&type=per)

The site is really self explaining.

However, if I use a different browser than firefox (which works perfectly for my purpose here), 
the first link opens up in a new tab as intended while later following links appear in a window-style popup which is very ugly and not what I'm trying to achieve here.

The code for the opening of the link is this:

```
$("#openLink").click(function(){     
for(var i=0;i<theLinks.length;i++){
    var elim = theLinks[i].replace(/\"/g,'');  //eliminate double quotes
    window.open(elim,'_blank');
}

});
```

From researching I found out I could use JQuery's click() function directly on links in the HTML-DOM, but as I expected this had not the effect I wanted (and did not work correctly at all)....

An important note here is that I can't use AJAX here for reasons of the implementation.
(I can post snippets from my php file if this really was needed)

If anybody could help me I was really thankfull, also if you have any tipps for me to improve usability and safty of the page!

EDIT:
I have tryed creating a mouse click event with

```
var a = window.document.createElement("a");
     a.target = '_blank';
     a.href = elim;

// Dispatch fake click
    var e = window.document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(e); //hope I got this example right
```

However, for Opera it still openes all tabs after the first in pop-up windows. I know there is an option in the browser settings with which you can edit the browser behaviour on links. Unfortunately I can't set it for the user and I cannot imposition each user to do this. Still worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing '_blank' with a name. That will open all links in the same new tab opened. Should work in most browsers.

So:

```
    window.open(elim,'SomeNameHere');
```

Comment: I tryed this, but the result was it did not work anymore, or to be more specific it just opens the last tab in the array.

Comment: Ah, now I get your answere right. You are perfectly right, but I want the links to open in DIFFERENT tabs. Ty anyway

Comment: Then just change the name with every tab you open, and it opens them in different tabs. So for example: `window.open(elim,'Tab'+i)` with `i` being a counter.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
window.open('','');
```

It should work.

Comment: How would I open the specific url then? Can I edit the new tab after I opened it? This would be very unsecure right?

Comment: I believe if you use window.open('','http://urlHere.com'); it should open the specific webpage.